# Undefined reference to static variable with -O0 optimization [stm32 template Pins]

Tags: c++, gdb, compiler-optimization, undefined-reference

I write program for STM32F100x in Eclipse. For convenience, I use [this template class](http://pastebin.com/ymebuuV2) for pins control.

And I have such code:

```
...
Pin<'C', 6>     temp_ok;
Pin<'C', 7>     temp_fail;
...
int main()
{
   ...
   if(temperature > 30)
   {
       temp_ok.Off();
       temp_fail.On();
   }
   else
   {
       temp_fail.Off();
       temp_ok.On();
   }
   ...
}
```

When I compile with `-O3` optimization it is compiled OK, but obviously I can't debug my program (Eclipse writes "no source avaible for main() 0x....".

To debug I should use `-O0` optimization, but when I try compile with `-O0` flag I have errors like this:

> undefined reference to `Pin<(char)67, 11, (char)72>::GPIOx

Using google I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973038/g-stops-on-undefined-reference-when-using-o0). After read I understood, that I need explicit declaration of `GPIOx` static variable.

So I started to search `GPIOx` static variable in [Pin class](http://pastebin.com/ymebuuV2) and I have found this:

```
template<char port, int pin_no, char activestate>
struct Pin
{
    enum { GPIOx_BASE = port_gpio_t<port>::GPIOx_BASE };
    enum { IDR_BB_ADDR = PERIPH_BB_BASE + (GPIOx_BASE + offsetof(GPIO_TypeDef, IDR) - PERIPH_BASE) * 32 + pin_no * 4 };
    enum { ODR_BB_ADDR = PERIPH_BB_BASE + (GPIOx_BASE + offsetof(GPIO_TypeDef, ODR) - PERIPH_BASE) * 32 + pin_no * 4 };
    static struct
    {
        GPIO_TypeDef* operator-> () { return (GPIO_TypeDef*)GPIOx_BASE; }
    }GPIOx;
...
...other code
```

But I can't understand what code I should write to initialize unnamed struct?

---

**Compiler:** arm-cortex-eabi-g++ v4.7.2

**Debugger:** arm-none-eabi-gdb v7.10.1 + OpenOCD + JLink

**IDE:** Eclipse + CDT

**OS:** Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: I think this question is not related to [stm32] but only to C++ compiler/linker issues. STM32 controllers are only the kind of ARM Cortex-M controllers the class was targeted on. But the problem relates to how to use the library, not the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Right at the top of the linked header:

```
USAGE:
*
*   I. Declare pin typedef:
* typedef Pin<'A', 5, 'H'> PA5;    // PA5, active level = high
* typedef Pin<'A', 6> PA6;         // PA6, active level = high ('H' is default parameter)
```

so, try declaring it that way:

```
typedef Pin<'C', 6>     temp_ok;
typedef Pin<'C', 7>     temp_fail;
```

Comment: That does not help :(